# Show tabs in Multiple rows is gone

Tags: android-studio

I just updated my Android Studio on MacOS to Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1, and I discovered that the option to show tabs in multiple rows is no longer there.. which is very inconvenient as I find myself with tabs with half names :/

Is there a way to reactivate this option without rolling back to the previous Android Studio?

It used to show here:
[image: Android Studio Editor Tabs settings]